# Is u[-n] defined from negative infinity to zero as it is folding of u[n] or from negative infinity to -1?

Tags: discrete-signals

Folding of unit step function and definition of its boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u[n]$ is the unit-step function :

$$u[n] = \begin{cases} { 1 ~~~,~~~n \geq 0 \\ 0 ~~~,~~~ n < 0 } \end{cases}$$

then

$$u[-n] = \begin{cases} { 1 ~~~,~~~ -n \geq 0 \\ 0 ~~~,~~~ -n < 0 } \end{cases}$$

or stated as
$$u[-n] = \begin{cases} { 1 ~~~,~~~ n \leq 0 \\ 0 ~~~,~~~ n > 0 } \end{cases}$$

Hence, $u[-n]$ is **nonzero** for the range of $n \in (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Fat's right.  But this is an important difference between the conventional discrete-time unit step $u[n]$ and the continuous-time unit step $u(t)$.   While this is true for the continuous-time unit step:

$$ u(t)+u(-t) = 1 \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$

the same expression is not true for the discrete-time counterpart:

$$ u[n] + u[-n] \ne 1 \qquad n=0 $$

but it's almost true:

$$ u[n-1]+ u[-n] = 1 \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$